# vscode extension is it possible to pass args into a command markdown link?

Tags: visual-studio-code, arguments

I'm working on a vscode extension using the **HoverProvider** to supply some HTML links for the **MarkdownString**, the links themselves are my own commands that work fine (they are being registered and their function hits). Unfortunately I'm unable to pass any querystring values/arguments into the command function.

Is it possible to pass args via the MarkdownString so that the command function receives them?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hover-command",

.. snip snip ...
 "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "hover-command.say_hello",
        "title": "greetz"
      }
    ]
  },
```

In the **extension.ts** file

```
  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand("say_hello", async (hi: string) => {
      vscode.window.showInformationMessage(hi + ' greetz at ' + new Date());
    })
  );

and


  const selector: vscode.DocumentSelector = {
    scheme: "file",
    language: "*",
  };

  vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider(selector, {
    provideHover(
      doc: vscode.TextDocument,
      pos: vscode.Position,
      token: vscode.CancellationToken
    ): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.Hover> {
      return new Promise<vscode.Hover>((resolve, reject) => {
        const hoverMarkup = "[Greetings...](command:say_hello?hi=world)";
        if (hoverMarkup) {
          const mdstring = new vscode.MarkdownString(hoverMarkup);
          mdstring.isTrusted = true; // NOTE: this is needed to execute commands!!
          resolve(new vscode.Hover(mdstring));
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      }
      );
    },
  });
```

but the registered command vscode.window.showInformationMessage is **not** getting any arguments/query string values.  I have tried looking at **arguments** but still at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

A few examples from the VSC source code

```
[search the Marketplace](command:workbench.extensions.search?%22%40category%3A%5C%22scm%20providers%5C%22%22)

[Initialize Repository](command:git.init?%5Btrue%5D)

[configure](command:workbench.action.openSettings?%5B%22editor.formatOnSave%22%5D)
```

Comment: Great, thanks rioV8 I will give that a try. 
The %5B and %5D are URI escaped '[' and ']'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again @rioV8, after a few failed attempts there are a few steps to get command hover markdown links to work with arguments.

I'm using **TypeScript**, so I'll add an interface to define the shape of the **args**

```js
interface ISayHelloArgs {
  msg: string;
}
```

The **registered command** then uses this interface (you get a single object 'args')

```
  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand("say_hello", async (args: ISayHelloArgs) => {
      vscode.window.showInformationMessage(args.msg + ' greetz at ' + new Date());
    })
  );
```

The registered **HoverProvider** then build the **args** using **encodeURI** version of a **JSON** string.

```js
 vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider(selector, {
    provideHover(
      doc: vscode.TextDocument,
      pos: vscode.Position,
      token: vscode.CancellationToken
    ): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.Hover> {
      return new Promise<vscode.Hover>((resolve, reject) => {
        const args: ISayHelloArgs = { msg: 'hello' };
        const jsonArgs = JSON.stringify(args);
        const hoverMarkup = `[Greetings...](command:say_hello?${encodeURI(jsonArgs)})`;
        if (hoverMarkup) {
          const mdstring = new vscode.MarkdownString(hoverMarkup);
          mdstring.isTrusted = true; // NOTE: this is needed to execute commands!!
          resolve(new vscode.Hover(mdstring));
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      }
      );
    },
  });
```

This worked for me, hope it helps others.